# Formula-based list for data validation

Tags: vba, excel, validation

Please refer to the image attachment below. I want to ask for help regarding the semi-automation of the values D2:D6. Currently, they have the following formula:

```
=IF(C2="n/a",$D$12,IF(C2="","",IF(OR(TODAY()=C2,TODAY()>C2),$D$11,$D$10)))
```

Column C on the other hand has the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="n/a","N/A",IF(B2="","",$B$8-$B2))
```

Basically, what these formulas do is that after I input a value 'x' at column B, column C automatically indicates the date 'x' days before the start date on B8. Column D then indicates whether the deadline is due, not due, not applicable, or ready (D2:D6 is data validated with a list including D9:D13).

However, if a certain action is already completed, the "Ready" option is manually selected from the drop down list, which then erases the formula. What I wish to ask for help with is how do I return the erased formula in case the "Ready" option is just accidentally selected, or if my (not excel-capable) peers will need to reuse the form by just deleting items in column A and B.

What I tried doing was making the formula itself an option in the drop down list, but this doesn't adjust to the cell addresses for each item, and only shows one static value.

One option I thought of was to limit the data validation list with just the "Ready" option, so that the user can just delete the cell. A VBA code will then detect the blank cell and will return the formula it initially had. Unfortunately, I don't really know VBA or any programming. I can however understand and have managed to use and modify VBA codes posted in the internet according to my previous needs. I tried searching for a code, but to no avail.

If you could give me good references (not a whole book please) relative to this, I would really appreciate it. If you're feeling benevolent and help me with the coding, thanks! However, if there's a non-VBA solution, then I would really like to know more about this. Thanks all!

[Sample list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEV9.png)

Comment: You could go totally without VBA if you would split `Not Ready / Ready`and `Not yet due / Due` into two columns. The formula is then only needed to determine `Not yet due / Due`.

Comment: `IF(OR(TODAY()=C2,TODAY()>C2),$D$11,$D$10))` can also be written as `IF(TODAY()>=C2,$D$11,$D$10)`. And wouldn't that be the same as saying `IF(C2>TODAY(),$D$10,$D$11)`?

Comment: Using VBA to install a formula is the long way of using VBA to set a cell value. You must already have VBA to delete the formula. Therefore you already have VBA to control the value of that cell. Therefore you must either control that cell completely via VBA or not at all. What I don't understand is why you can't adjust your formula to take the selected "Ready" into account: execute the formula if the DD isn't "Ready" and show "Ready" if the DD shows "Ready". Is it because you have the formula and the DD in the same cell? Can you move the DD to an adjacent cell?

Comment: Hi @Alex Richter. Hmmm. I see. That's an excellent alternative. Thanks! However, I'm not sure if we're allowed to do this since the terms used in the data validation list is approved by our partners, and somehow I find it hard to change them. I would try to suggest this to them, but should there be solutions considering the original texts, I will highly appreciate it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AxelRichter, thanks for the advise. I ended up using your suggestion. Thanks!